# convergence of sum of "poisson many" Bernoulli RV

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $(\xi_n)_{n \geq 0}$ be a sequence of iid. Bernoulli random variables with $\mathbb{P}(\xi_k = 1) = \frac{1}{2}$ and $\mathbb{P}(\xi_k = -1) = \frac{1}{2}$. Let $N$ be poisson with parameter $\lambda > 0$. Let $Z_{\lambda} = \xi_1 + \xi_2 + ... + \xi_N$. Compute the characteristic function of $Z_{\lambda}$ and show that $\frac{Z_\lambda}{\sqrt{\lambda}}$ converges in distribution to a standard normal random variable as $\lambda$ goes to $\infty$.

I have computed the characteristic as follows: $\mathbb{E}\left[\exp(itZ_\lambda)\right] = \mathbb{E}\left[\exp(it\xi_1)\right] \cdot...\cdot \mathbb{E}\left[\exp(it\xi_N)\right]$

and $\mathbb{E}\left[\exp(it\xi_1)\right] = \frac{1}{2}\left(\exp(it)+exp(-it)\right) = \cos(t) $

hence $\mathbb{E}\left[\exp(itZ_\lambda)\right] = \cos(t)^N$.

Concerning the convergence I thought I could use the characteristic function since I have already computed it, i.e. show that $\mathbb{E}\left[\exp(itZ_\lambda)\right] = \exp\left(-\frac{t^2}{2}\right)$. How can I get there?

We are given the HINT: $\cos(t) = 1- \frac{t^2}{2} + O(t^4)$ as $t \rightarrow 0$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your expression $\cos(t)^N$ isn't $\mathbb E[\exp(itZ_\lambda)]$ -- more precisely, we have
$$\mathbb E[\exp(itZ_\lambda)\mid N]=\cos(t)^N.$$
To actually find $\mathbb E[\exp(itZ_\lambda]$, we can use the law of total expectation to get
$$\mathbb E[\exp(itZ_\lambda)]=\mathbb E[\mathbb E[\exp(itZ_\lambda)\mid N]]=\mathbb E[\cos(t)^N]=G(\cos t)=\exp(\lambda[-1+\cos t]),$$
where $G(z)$ is the PGF of $N\sim\operatorname{Poisson}(\lambda)$. Then considering $Z_\lambda/\sqrt{\lambda}$, and taking $\lambda\to\infty$,
\begin{align*}
\mathbb E[\exp(itZ_\lambda/\sqrt\lambda)]=\exp\left(\lambda\left[-1+\cos\frac{t}{\sqrt{\lambda}}\right]\right)&=\exp\left(\lambda\left[-\frac{t^2}{2\lambda}+O\left(\frac{t^4}{\lambda^2}\right)\right]\right)\\
&\to\exp(-t^2/2),
\end{align*}
which is what we wanted.